# Crash on opening drafts

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

After recent update I got the drafts menu item. When I open it app crashes

- App Version: 1.5.0.3
- Device: iPhone 5 (Global)
- OS Version: Version 8.1 (Build 12B411)

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in 1.5.1, shipping next week.

This is a mistake I've embarrassingly made before.  iOS 8 cannot infer the nib name for Swift view controllers so it fails to load the view, crashing the app.